# How to copy a file into a set of folders with the same structure?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a set of folder with the same structure, for example:

```
folder1_name/global/thumbnails/
folder2_name/global/thumbnails/
folder3_name/global/thumbnails/

...

folder100_name/global/thumbnails/
```

How can I copy a file into the "thumbnails" folder of all "folderN_name"?

What I intended to do is:

```
cp my_file folder*_name/global/thumbnails/
```

but it is not working. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash `for` loop is your friend:

```
for i in folder*_name/global/thumbnails/; do
  cp my_file $i
done
```

Comment: for i in folder*_name/global/thumbnails/; do cp my_file $i; done      ------> it works for me. And I think it's a neat and elegant way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use one destination directory at a time, a simple loop would do:

```
for i in folder*_name/global/thumbnails/; do [ -d "$i" ] && cp my_file "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` with `xargs`:

```
find folder[0-9]_name/global/thumbnails/ -type d | xargs -I {} cp my_file {}
```

Comment: too complicated to remember. Thanks.

Comment: It is fairly standard `find+xargs` combo being used in many commands that does the job without any loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate N copy commands something like

```
 for target in folder*_name/global/thumbnails/
 do
     echo "copying my_file into $target"
     cp my_file $target
 done
```

I added the echo command in there so you can see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

The * notation won't work with `cp` like you want.

You'll need a loop:

```
for i in {1..100}; do
        cp your_file folder$i\_name/global/thumbnails/
done
```